# Setting window size and position in PowerShell 5 and 6

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

**Problem**: We have a large television we use for presentations, that isn't exactly 1920×1080 px. It's off and I can't control it. What I can control is my windows laptop that I connect to it. I have been looking for ways to get whatever I need displayed, to move over to the projector, set a position that is offset for looking good on the tv, and set the width/height for the same.

**What's been done**: I can use Boe Prox's Get-Window script (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/12/26/weekend-scripter-manage-window-placement-by-using-pinvoke/), and that worked fine, to get me the dimensions and offset I need. However, his Set-Window errors on me in both WinPosh 5 and Posh 6 with and without Admin privilege. Other potential solutions produced similar errors, so I decided to stay with Prox's script, as he's an expert by my standards.

I am evaluating solutions mentioned here,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392620/how-can-a-batch-file-run-a-program-and-set-the-position-and-size-of-the-window/ as **possible workarounds**. However, a PowerShell solution without dependencies on anything third party would be ideal.

**The question is:**
Has anyone solved how to get either Mr. Prox's Set-Window or anything else to set a windows position and size in straight v5 or v6 PowerShell?

Error Message in Posh 5:

```
Cannot convert argument "hWnd", with value: "System.Object[]", for "GetWindowRect" to type "System.IntPtr": "Cannot
convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.IntPtr"."
At Z:\scripts\Set-Window.ps1:90 char:9
+         $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Error Messages in Posh 6:

```
PS C:\> Set-Window -ProcessName notepad -X 1911 -Y "-369" -Width 266 -Height 113
Method invocation failed because [Window] does not contain a method named 'MoveWindow'.
At Z:\scripts\Set-Window.ps1:98 char:13
+             $Return = [Window]::MoveWindow($Handle, $x, $y, $Width, $ ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound


PS C:\> Set-Window -ProcessName firefox -X "-9" -Y "-9" -Width "1938" -Height "1050"
Cannot convert argument "hWnd", with value: "System.Object[]", for "GetWindowRect" to type "System.IntPtr": "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.IntPtr"."
At Z:\scripts\Set-Window.ps1:90 char:9
+         $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Note: These errors occur in Windows 7 (no access to Win10 for a while).

Update: I had noticed [Set (Many) Programs' Window Size/Position](https://superuser.com/questions/769575/set-many-programs-window-size-position), but the UIAutomation module isn't maintained (codeplex is archived, and last blog post by the author for it, was Feb 2014).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By default, `Get-Process` cmdlet returns a `System.Diagnostics.Process` object - or an **array** of such object if there are more matching processes. Unfortunately, the original [`Set-Window.ps1` script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-the-position-and-size-54853527) does not reflect the latter scenario.

**Output** using improved script:

```
PS D:\PShell> Get-Process -ProcessName notepad

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    505      29    12104      41232       2,05   4208   1 notepad
    231      14     3068      13212       0,09   6732   1 notepad

PS D:\PShell> . D:\PShell\Downloaded\WindowManipulation\Set-Window.ps1

PS D:\PShell> Set-Window -ProcessName notepad -X 11 -Y 11 -Width 1200 -Height 900 -Passthru

ProcessName Size     TopLeft BottomRight
----------- ----     ------- -----------
notepad     1200,900 11,11   1211,911
notepad     1200,900 11,11   1211,911


PS D:\PShell>
```

### Edit.

**Improved script** (changes commented): see [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1324170/revisions).

**Enhanced script**, the latest version:

- new input parameter `Id` (process Id);
- process Id added to output for better insight.

Some minor changes to verbose and warning output.

```
Function Set-Window {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Retrieve/Set the window size and coordinates of a process window.

.DESCRIPTION
Retrieve/Set the size (height,width) and coordinates (x,y) 
of a process window.

.PARAMETER ProcessName
Name of the process to determine the window characteristics. 
(All processes if omitted).

.PARAMETER Id
Id of the process to determine the window characteristics. 

.PARAMETER X
Set the position of the window in pixels from the left.

.PARAMETER Y
Set the position of the window in pixels from the top.

.PARAMETER Width
Set the width of the window.

.PARAMETER Height
Set the height of the window.

.PARAMETER Passthru
Returns the output object of the window.

.NOTES
Name:   Set-Window
Author: Boe Prox
Version History:
    1.0//Boe Prox - 11/24/2015 - Initial build
    1.1//JosefZ   - 19.05.2018 - Treats more process instances 
                                 of supplied process name properly
    1.2//JosefZ   - 21.02.2019 - Parameter Id

.OUTPUTS
None
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
System.Object

.EXAMPLE
Get-Process powershell | Set-Window -X 20 -Y 40 -Passthru -Verbose
VERBOSE: powershell (Id=11140, Handle=132410)

Id          : 11140
ProcessName : powershell
Size        : 1134,781
TopLeft     : 20,40
BottomRight : 1154,821

Description: Set the coordinates on the window for the process PowerShell.exe

.EXAMPLE
$windowArray = Set-Window -Passthru
WARNING: cmd (1096) is minimized! Coordinates will not be accurate.

    PS C:\>$windowArray | Format-Table -AutoSize

  Id ProcessName    Size     TopLeft       BottomRight  
  -- -----------    ----     -------       -----------  
1096 cmd            199,34   -32000,-32000 -31801,-31966
4088 explorer       1280,50  0,974         1280,1024    
6880 powershell     1280,974 0,0           1280,974     

Description: Get the coordinates of all visible windows and save them into the
             $windowArray variable. Then, display them in a table view.

.EXAMPLE
Set-Window -Id $PID -Passthru | Format-Table
​‌‍
  Id ProcessName Size     TopLeft BottomRight
  -- ----------- ----     ------- -----------
7840 pwsh        1024,638 0,0     1024,638

Description: Display the coordinates of the window for the current 
             PowerShell session in a table view.



#>
[cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Name')]
Param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$False,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True, ParameterSetName='Name')]
    [string]$ProcessName='*',
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True,
        ValueFromPipeline=$False,              ParameterSetName='Id')]
    [int]$Id,
    [int]$X,
    [int]$Y,
    [int]$Width,
    [int]$Height,
    [switch]$Passthru
)
Begin {
    Try { 
        [void][Window]
    } Catch {
    Add-Type @"
        using System;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
        public class Window {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool GetWindowRect(
            IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public extern static bool MoveWindow( 
            IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool ShowWindow(
            IntPtr handle, int state);
        }
        public struct RECT
        {
        public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
        public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
        public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
        public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
        }
"@
    }
}
Process {
    $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
    If ( $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Id') ) {
        $Processes = Get-Process -Id $Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    } else {
        $Processes = Get-Process -Name "$ProcessName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    if ( $null -eq $Processes ) {
        If ( $PSBoundParameters['Passthru'] ) {
            Write-Warning 'No process match criteria specified'
        }
    } else {
        $Processes | ForEach-Object {
            $Handle = $_.MainWindowHandle
            Write-Verbose "$($_.ProcessName) `(Id=$($_.Id), Handle=$Handle`)"
            if ( $Handle -eq [System.IntPtr]::Zero ) { return }
            $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
            If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('X')) {
                $X = $Rectangle.Left            
            }
            If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Y')) {
                $Y = $Rectangle.Top
            }
            If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Width')) {
                $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left
            }
            If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Height')) {
                $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
            }
            If ( $Return ) {
                $Return = [Window]::MoveWindow($Handle, $x, $y, $Width, $Height,$True)
            }
            If ( $PSBoundParameters['Passthru'] ) {
                $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
                $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
                If ( $Return ) {
                    $Height      = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
                    $Width       = $Rectangle.Right  - $Rectangle.Left
                    $Size        = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size        -ArgumentList $Width, $Height
                    $TopLeft     = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Left , $Rectangle.Top
                    $BottomRight = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Right, $Rectangle.Bottom
                    If ($Rectangle.Top    -lt 0 -AND 
                        $Rectangle.Bottom -lt 0 -AND
                        $Rectangle.Left   -lt 0 -AND
                        $Rectangle.Right  -lt 0) {
                        Write-Warning "$($_.ProcessName) `($($_.Id)`) is minimized! Coordinates will not be accurate."
                    }
                    $Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
                        Id          = $_.Id
                        ProcessName = $_.ProcessName
                        Size        = $Size
                        TopLeft     = $TopLeft
                        BottomRight = $BottomRight
                    }
                    $Object
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: That successfully works in both v5 and v6. Thank you for teaching me something!

Comment: I also had to change "User32.dll" to "user32.dll" on Windows 10 / PowerShell:
```
 [DllImport("User32.dll")]
                public extern static bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);
              }
```

to (note lower-case u)
```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
                public extern static bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);
              }
```

Comment: Just saying for a MAXIMISED window [Window]::ShowWindow($Handle, 1) seems to be required  -I also tried 5 and 8 which did not work

Comment: At the very end of JosefZ's script I've appended a single line *$windowArray | Format-Table -AutoSize* and nothing outputs in result, just a blank line - no error, not anything.  According to the notes inside his set-window function, that command should output a formatted table of positions of all open Desktop windows.  I'm running PowerShell version 5.1.14409.1027.

Comment: @T-Heron you need `$windowArray = Set-Window -Passthru` first…

Comment: That works.  Thanks!!!!  +1